# How to assign the cat output of a bash script to a variable in another script

Tags: shell-script, cat, variable

I have a bash script that produces a cat output when it takes an argument. I also have another bash script that executes the first bash script with an an argument that I want to produce cat outputs with. How do I store those cat outputs produced by the first bash script in variables?

Answer (score 79):

```
var=$( cat foo.txt )
```

would store the output of the `cat` in variable `var`.

```
var=$( ./myscript )
```

would store the output of `myscript` in the same variable.

Comment: quick tip for bash newbies like me, the spacing & non spacing are all important, follow exact pattern! for example `var = $( cat foo.txt )` will not work

Comment: @Dalker is there a limit how big the foo.txt can be? I have over 10 mb of data. Would cat store the whole thing? I want to know if there's a limit also for future reference.

Comment: @sojim Do you know the answer of this?

Comment: @myhouse According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5076416/613191) there is no limit due to bash itself, but the limit is rather the memory allocated on the underlying environment, which may of course vary.

Answer (score 6):

Use the double quotes. Try this

```
var="$(cat foo.txt)"
```

Comment: It's almost never a bad idea to put things (especially things that begin with `$`) into double quotes, and it doesn't hurt here. However, in the case of assignment to a variable, it doesn't actually help.

Comment: @G-Man: What if that variable contains newlines or tabs that we want to stay in the variable?

Comment: @jvriesem:  What if it does?   Do you have a question?

Comment: When I run this command, it seems to get rid of all of my newlines.

Comment: @K.Carpenter echo $var would get rid of newlines, but echo "$var" should show the new lines